# Issue in creating tenants in WSO2 EMM (2.0.1)

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I am trying to create tenants in WSO2 EMM(2.0.1), but the tenants are not getting reflected in the store. As compared to WSO2 App-Manager we get to see the tenants in the store ,but in WSO2 EMM the tenants are not visible.How to see those tanants? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain you use case in detail? You can create tenants from the EMM management console.(https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Tenant+Management)

Comment: @sashika you can provide the correct solution as an answer so the user can close this. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 EMM console which can be accessed by the "emm" context dose not the support of configuration of the server to the level you are expecting to manage.
Please login to the carbon management console which can be accessed by the "carbon" context.

> https://yourdomain.com/carbon

You can visit the configuration tab and then multi-tenancy section.
Please follow the documentation provided by sashika above for more info.